# OpenPyXL: Compare a string in a cell to a string set to print all cell values in row

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I've been using Python with OpenPyXL to access an Excel file with 3000+ rows. I've been trying to print whole rows (or certain cell values in rows) containing a string cell value that I want to search but it seems I encounter an error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

This is the code I'm using (For now, I'm just trying to output the cell.value of the cell containing the string I want to search but I want to output a certain cell in the row or the whole row itself)

```
>>> from openpyxl import *
>>> wb = load_workbook('C:\Users\Aldwin\Desktop\Excel1.xlsx',read_only=True)
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, min_col=1):
    for cell in row:
        if 'DRLDMEM' in cell.value:   #String I want to search: 'DRLDMEM'
            print(cell.value, end=" ")
    print()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#19>", line 3, in <module>
    if 'DRLDMEM' in cell.value:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

When I do a check on individual cells it works. Say, cell AA13 contains a part of the string:

```
>>> print(ws['AA13'].value)
DRLDMEM, READ, PCINC
>>> 'DRLDMEM' in ws['AA13'].value
True
```

I want to output print like this:

```
T1  FETCH2:     DR←M, PC←PC+1       DRLDMEM, READ, PCINC            
T3  SUBIMM1:    DR←M                DRLDMEM, READ
T3  ANDIMM1:    DR←M                DRLDMEM, READ
```

Out of 3000+ rows, the output desired are only the rows with a cell that has DRLDMEM (or preferably, the cell with values: FETCH2, SUBIMM1, ANDIMM1)

I don't know what to do to solve this. Any thoughts and suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: `cell.value` isn't always a string. You have to check if it's a string before you try to check `if 'DRLDMEM' in cell.value`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. May I ask to elaborate how the distinction contributes to the problem? Also, most of the cells in the excel files are words/strings so I'm  not sure if that is the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When a cell has the value `None`, your code throws that exception. It's the _direct cause_ of your problem.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! That fixed it! I added an if statement "if cell.value is not None:" and nested under, "if type(cell.value) != int:" and it iterated. Thank you :) I'd only like to ask for your help one more time: as stated above, do you have any ideas to point me to the direction where I display the desired output above? (The ones with rows) Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, code works. Slow though, any ideas how to make it faster?

```
>>> from openpyxl import *
>>> wb = load_workbook('C:/Users/MyPlace/Desktop/MyWork.xlsx',read_only=True)
>>> ws = wb["Sheet1"]
>>> for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, min_col=1):
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value is not None:
                if type(cell.value) != int:
                    if 'PCINC' in cell.value:
                        #print(cell.coordinate +' ' + cell.value, )
                        a = cell.row
                        for i in range(1,30):
                            if ws.cell(row=a,column=i).value is not None:
                                print(ws.cell(row=a,column=i).value,end=' ')
                        print()
OUTPUT:

T6 JMP4: PC[15-8]←TEMPH, PC[7-0]←TEMPL PCLD, THABUSLD, TLABUSLD, SCCLR 
T6 JMPZ4: PC [15-8]←TEMP H PCLD, THABUSLD, TLABUSLD, SCCLR 
T6 JMPNZ6: PC [15-8] ←TEMP H PCLD, THABUSLD, TLABUSLD, SCCLR 
T6 JMPO4: PC [15-8]←TEMP H PCLD, THABUSLD, TLABUSLD, SCCLR 
T6 JMPNO6: PC [15-8]←TEMP H PCLD, THABUSLD, TLABUSLD, SCCLR 
T6 JMPC4: PC [15-8]←TEMP H PCLD, THABUSLD, TLABUSLD, SCCLR 
T6 JMPNC6: PC[15-8]←TEMP H PCLD, THABUSLD, TLABUSLD, SCCLR 
T6 JMPS4: PC[15-8]←TEMP H PCLD, THABUSLD, TLABUSLD, SCCLR 
T6 JMPNS6: PC[15-8]←TEMP H PCLD, THABUSLD, TLABUSLD, SCCLR 
T8 CALL6: AR←SP, DR←PC [7-0] ARLD, SPABUSLD, DRLD, PCLDBUSLD 
T9 CALL7: M←DR,  DRTOMEM, PCLD, THABUSLD, TLABUSLD, WRITE 
T8 RET6: PC [15-8] ←TEMP H PCLD, THABUSLD, TLABUSLD, SCCLR 
T7 LDINDAC5: DR←M, PC←AR DRLDMEM, READ, PCLD, ARABUSLD
```